# Accessing database info in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I'm having trouble defining an amount for a pay action in my item controller.  I'm trying to pull in the item price stored in the db.  I've tried everything.  I reread this, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html, and still no luck.

In items controller:

```
def pay
    # Find the user to pay.
    user = User.find( params[:id] )
    amount = #I have no idea what to put here
    fee = 100
```

If I put in a number it works fine.  However when I try to access the item price that is stored in the db, that is when things blow up.

I've tried various definitions:

```
@item.price #fail
item_price #fail
Item.find (params: [:price]) #fail
Item.price #fail
 #EVERYTHING FAILS
```

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150127171203) do

create_table "items", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "booth_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image"
    t.string   "image_two"
  end

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.string   "activation_digest"
    t.boolean  "activated",         default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string   "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.boolean  "admin",             default: false
    t.string   "avatar"
    t.text     "about"
    t.string   "location"
    t.string   "publishable_key"
    t.string   "secret_key"
    t.string   "stripe_user_id"
    t.string   "currency"
  end
```

(edit) I also tried defining items in the pay action and that did not help either.  'item = Item.find ( params[:id]'

Does anyone know the right way to do this?  I feel like this should be easy but I'm having trouble with it.

Thanks for your consideration and help!

Comment: What error code are you getting? Do you have a price column in your items table in your database?

Answer (score 1):

How is a user related to an item? I ask this because if you are using active record, the associations you make in your database will determine the methods that are created for you. Does a user `has_many` items in your model? Does an item `belong_to` a user? In which case would be

```
@user = User.find(1)
```

and you could find the price like

```
@item = @user.items.find(1)
@price = @item.price
```

#### EDIT

Ok, I took a look at the code you provided [here](https://github.com/rfunduk/rails-stripe-connect-example/blob/master/app/controllers/users_controller.rb). This example shows a pay method defining a route in the users controller which seems to only be setup to accept a one time fee. In the comments above it, it even says make a one-off payment so we know this is true.

Even in this example [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails) they explicitly say it's for a fixed amount. Now how do we make it dynamic? Well, look at the code. There's some logic in the pay controller isn't there?

You see that Stripe::Charge object being created?

```
charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        {
          amount: amount,
          currency: user.currency,
          card: params[:token],
          description: "Test Charge via Stripe Connect",
          application_fee: fee
        },

        # Use the user-to-be-paid's access token
        # to make the charge.
        user.secret_key
      )
```

You can move this logic into your item MODEL. Call it pay or something as long as it takes in the user as a parameter.

```
def pay(user)

amount = self.price

begin
  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    {
      amount: amount,
      currency: user.currency,
      card: user.token,
      description: "Test Charge via Stripe Connect",
      application_fee: fee
    },

    # Use the user-to-be-paid's access token
    # to make the charge.
    user.secret_key
  )
  flash[:notice] = "Charged successfully! <a target='_blank' rel='connected-account' href='https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/payments/#{charge.id}'>View in dashboard &raquo;</a>"

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  error = e.json_body[:error][:message]
  flash[:error] = "Charge failed! #{error}"
end

end
```

Then somewhere in your items CONTROLLER define the pay method instead of users like you had before(Make sure you change your routes accordingly). Then call the pay method you just defined, this way you have the price and you can find the user that is currently logged in.

```
def pay
user = User.find(session[:user_id])
item = Item.find(params[:id])
item.pay(user)

redirect "somewhere"
end
```

Comment: The item belongs to the user and the user has many items (the pay action is in the items controller).  I did something similar to what you are suggesting, 
item = Item.find (params [:id])
amount = item.price
And I get the error "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Comment: Could you perhaps provide the code for your user and item migrations along with their models? Or is this code up on GitHub somewhere I can take a look at?

Comment: Yes, I'll add that now.  Thanks!

Comment: In your items controller, do you have a create method that creates an item record? Are there items seeded for us in the database to actually find?

Comment: Oh btw it's params[:id] maybe it's just a syntax error. Make sure there's no space between params and []

Comment: I turned out to be a capitalization error, but now it only finds the price for the 1st item in the db and uses that price for every item:  

'item = Item.find (params[:id])
    amount = item.price  '

Does anyone know how to make it find the specific item?  I tried 'amount = item.price, item' and a few other variations of that but I'm not getting it right.  If anyone can help me I can add the complete answer.  Thanks a lot!

Oh, and yes there are actual items in the db to find.

Comment: Yea that's because you are using the .find method which takes an id, and returns that record matching the id. Not only that, you are defining a pay method in your items controller which is incorrect. Please read RESTful architecture in Rails http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html. You should write a pay method in your item model because Rails follows a fat models and skinny controllers paradigm. That way you would remove all the logic away from the controller and into the model. Then you would call that method in your view when the pay button is clicked.

Comment: OK, I will reread this.  The example provided by Stripe had the pay action in the controller and not the model.

Comment: Could you provide the link to Stripe's documentation? I'd like to take a look at what you're working with.

Comment: Yes, here you go: https://github.com/rfunduk/rails-stripe-connect-example/blob/master/app/controllers/users_controller.rb  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I took a look at the code. This example shows a pay method defining a route in the users controller which seems to only be setup to accept a one time fee. In the comments above it, it even says make a one-off payment so we know this is true. Even in this example [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails) they explicitly say it's for a fixed amount. Now how do we make it dynamic? Well, look at the code. There's some logic in the pay controller isn't there? You see that Stripe::Charge object being created?

Comment: That should belong in the item Model. It should take a parameter user because that way you already have the price for the specific item. This comment is too long so I'm about to post another answer to show you some code.

Comment: Cool. Can I have an up vote so I can get my magic internet points? You can email me directly if you need help.

Comment: My only thought is that I don't want to find the user that is currently logged in, I want to find the user that posted the item since that is the user that needs to be paid.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yea your items table has a foreign id for users. Use that. .where() and .find_by()

Comment: .find only takes an id. Where and find by you can query other fields.

Comment: In other words, your item should have a item.user_id based on those associations as long as when the user that posted the item gets assigned to that item in your create method in items controller.